# How to speed up balance scanning of addresses?

Tags: balance, android-wallet, monejuro

Scanning for an updated balance takes a very long time. I was thinking of getting a high powered cpu like a 32 core AMD threadripper to speed things up while running a remote node with monejuro on android.

- Does CPU performance affect scanning time substantially?
- When using the android monejuro android app, does the scanning happen on the phone or on the remote server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CPU performance does affect scanning time, but so too does Disk I/O speed, and having a sufficient amount of RAM. By the sounds of it you want to set up your own remote node to connect to from your phone?

And yes, my understanding is that when you connect to a remote node, the scanning happens server side, so this should work in theory.

My question to you is, why wouldn't you just use an existing remote node? Unless you are very concerned about your IP address being logged by a remote node operator, using a remote daemon does not compromise the security of your funds. I am unsure whether remote nodes can see your transaction history or not though. Could someone else clarify that?

Comment: if this happens server side, won't public monero nodes be easily hogged up and lagged if more than 10 people are scanning?